# Error installing pixiedust in using Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pixiedust

I hope you're doing well.

I am trying to follow the Pixiedust installation as laid out on the official github (https://pixiedust.github.io/pixiedust/install.html), and install it in windows 10 (64 bit).
when I try to execute instruction “jupyter pixiedust install”  I get this error as “OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application”. Let me say this too I was installed Spark (2.4.7)  before. I will be very grateful if you help me.

```
(base) C:\>jupyter pixiedust install
←[32;1mStep 1: PIXIEDUST_HOME: C:\Pixiedust←[0m
        Keep y/n [y]? y
←[32;1mStep 2: SPARK_HOME: C:\Spark\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7←[0m
        Keep y/n [y]? y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-pixiedust-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pixiedust', 'console_scripts', 'jupyter-pixiedust')())
  File "c:\pixiedust\install\pixiedustapp.py", line 41, in main
    PixiedustJupyterApp.launch_instance()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 333, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 684, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 603, in initialize_subcommand
    self.subapp.initialize(argv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 241, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "c:\pixiedust\install\createKernel.py", line 154, in parse_command_line
    spark_version = self.get_spark_version()
  File "c:\pixiedust\install\createKernel.py", line 379, in get_spark_version
    pyspark_out = subprocess.check_output([pyspark, "--version"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

(base) C:\>
```

Comment: Hi Amin, as far as I know Pixiedust is no longer under active development.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank you so much.